# Getting Access Token Data From OAuth Template of Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oauth

I'm trying to get access token of facebook client when a user logged in with asp.net's oauth template. But I couldn't acquire the access token when i tried some methods that i found on internet like;

```
AuthenticationResult result = OpenAuth.VerifyAuthentication("RegisterExternalLogin.aspx");                
string actok = result.ExtraData["accesstoken"];
```

This try wasn't successfull. How can i acquire the access token?

Answer (score 1):

I see noone has replied to your question even though it has been 10 days so I'll take a stab at it.

You mentioned that you are using asp.net's OAuth template. So I think you are looking at the line

```
AuthenticationResult result = OpenAuth.VerifyAuthentication("RegisterExternalLogin.aspx");
```

in the ExternalLoginCallback() action in AccountController.cs

As far as I can tell your syntax is correct. In fact also tested it out myself and it works. I guess you can try another way of accessing the same property

```
String myaccesstoken_value1 = result.ExtraData.Values.ToArray()[5];
```

That will give you the same result as result.ExtraData["accesstoken"]

If that does not work either then I would imagine that there is some problem with the authentication itself, rather than with your syntax here. I'm assuming you have VS2012 Express, so use the debugger to see what values are present in your variable 'result'. If it is empty, then it would indicate why you second statement errors out, and it would also indicate that there is a problem in the code before you get to this point.

Also keep in mind during testing that when you log into your app using OAuth providers such as Facebook, even when you log out of the website you continue to remain logged into facebook. You actually have to go to facebook.com and click logout there also (unless you write some additional code in your asp.net app to do a remote logout). I don't know if this applies to your situation, just giving you a heads up.

Please vote if this helps.